Applying formula to cell (whole column) itself in excel
I have a big datasheet of negative values in excel, and I want to convert them into positive ones without unsing a new column for calculation.
In other words, is there any method to apply a formula to a whole column  itself or create formulas that can do self-reference?
Thanks in advance!

Put -1 in a new cell, copy it, then select your column and paste special > multiply.

Simple place -1 in some blank cell, copy it and select the whole data what you have. Hit ALT+H+V+S --> Select Values --> Select Operation as Multiply if i am mistaking something please let me know

Silly question but worth asking, are any of the values positive? I know you said no other columns, but if this is a possibility I would use a helper column and ABS() and then copy the data over the old data as values and delete the helper.
